# Matplotlib bar chart_ get unexpected chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have df as below

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xs4z5.png)

I try to draw bar chart of revenue by using matplotlib but my chart displayed was not expected.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,15))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,7),(0,0),colspan=3,rowspan=2)
ax1.bar(df.index,df['revenue'],width=30,label='Revenue',align='center')
plt.show()
```

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4p7FU.png)

while i want my chart look like this 
[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwaJn.png)

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option that may make things simpler is to use the pandas plotting option. Depending on your use case it has pretty good defaults and you can still access all the underlying mpl settings if you want to make changes.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({'Year': [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018],
                   'revenue': [15756726, 25252733, 44613332.0, 66339804.0, 22763520.0],
                   'gross_income': [2396119, 3922431, 7214106, 11141780, 3974763],
                   'profit_before_tax': [868197, 1385783, 2005910, 28809313, 1042985],
                   'Expected_PBT': [np.NaN, 886000, 1388000, 2200000, 2603000]
                   }).set_index('Year')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 15))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 7), loc=(0, 0), colspan=3, rowspan=2)
df['revenue'].plot(kind='bar', ax=ax1, legend=True, rot=0, title='Requested Plot')

ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6, 7), loc=(0, 3), colspan=3, rowspan=2)
df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax2, legend=True, rot=0, title='Additional Example')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: you are welcome. I added another example for you that you will hopefully find helpful. Normally I would go through and rename the columns since they get used for labels with str.title and strip the underscores.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a smaller width and call ax.legend()

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[2014,2015,2016,2017, 2018],'revenue':[15756726, 25252733, 44613332.0, 66339804.0, 22763520.0]}).set_index('Year')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,15))
ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,7),(0,0),colspan=3,rowspan=2)
ax1.bar(df.index,df['revenue'],width=0.5,label='Revenue',align='center')
ax1.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ken, it still does not work well as i want separate bar for each year.

Comment: @DuongBui can you copy your dataframe to your question? Or quickly try ‘fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)’ to see if the problem is solved.

Comment: @DuongBui I just get it done by further reducing the width. cheers.